# how can I use this function parameter

Tags: function, parameters

I couldn't use the parameter 'img_sel' in function.
The parameter  value is get properly in function when I test by alert().
What is wrong?
Thanks

```
function selectfile(img_sel){                   
                var adres = '../images/';
                adres += document.querySelector('#img_01_val').value = document.querySelector('#imagename01').innerHTML = document.querySelector(img_sel).value; 
                document.querySelector('#img_01_img').src = adres;
            }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what are you passing as param to the function?

Comment: <select id="img_01_sel" onchange="selectfile('img_01_sel')">
the form element what calls the function.

Comment: and the error message in console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at selectfile (dirlist.php:7)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (dirlist.php:17)
selectfile @ dirlist.php:7
onchange @ dirlist.php:17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem here is that you are using the `querySelector` function, which needs a CSS selector.

For solving this you can either change the `querySelector` to `getElementById` or add a '#' in your selectfile function before the 'img_sel'

Comment: Yes I solved like that:

document.querySelector('#'+img_sel).value

Thank you